# Simpson's rule with ListConvolve or ListCorrelate

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-integration

I have a function that's represented as a long list of values that I want to integrate. I can do it procedurally with Simpson's rule. ListConvolve generally runs faster then procedural code, so i would like to use it if I can find the right kernel.

My list can be of even or odd length, and for the latter I would like to use a method that is better than the trapezoid method. Is there a higher order method for this case?

Comment: How about `Interpolation` and `NIntegrate` with an appropriate rule for `Method`?

Comment: @rm, even `Integrate[]` would work nicely for interpolating functions.

Comment: In any event, Bob, did you know there are *two* Simpson's rules? One of them (the less popular one) would work nicely when the number of intervals is a multiple of $3$...

Comment: Could just set up the `{1,4,2,4,2,...,4,2,1}` vector and use `Dot`.

Comment: Also related: the upgrade information for [ListIntegrate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/FunctionApproximations/ref/ListIntegrate.html), an obsolete function.

Answer (score 6):

As I mentioned in my comment, the easiest way to integrate a list of values is to use `Interpolation` with `Integrate` or `NIntegrate`. As [Jens noted](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26882/simpsons-rule-with-listconvolve-or-listcorrelate#comment83803_26882), the upgrade information for `ListIntegrate`, an obsolete function also mentions the same thing. For the sake of completeness, here's how you'd do it:

```
With[{if = Interpolation[(* list of {x, y} pairs *), InterpolationOrder -> k}, 
    Integrate[if[x], {x, Sequence @@ if["Domain"][[1]]}]
]
```

If you really do wish to use Simpson's rule specifically (perhaps, for a homework or to reproduce some other result), you can also do what Daniel suggested, which is to set up the vector for Simpson's rule (or the 3/8ths rule), $\{1,4,2,4,2,\ldots,4,2,1\}$ and use `Dot`.

Comment: Great to see this answer @rm -rf♦ Sometimes, the combination of `Interpolation` and  `NIntegrate` makes the integration very slow. See [Michael's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/192736/55777). Is it possible to use a quadrature rule, say, trapezoidal integration, to implement the integral in that equation in order to speed up the code? Thank you.