# Solving an integro-differential equation with Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, integral-equations

I try to solve a nonlinear integro-differential equation with this code. Here i used a periodic condition.

```
L=10; tmax = 2;

NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x] + D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + 
D[u[x, t], {x, 4}] + 1/(2 L)*NIntegrate[D[u[xp, t],{xp, 3}]*Cot[\[Pi](x - xp)/(2*L)], {xp, -L, x, L}, Method -> {"PrincipalValue"}] == 0,
u[-L, t] == u[L, t], u[x, 0] == 0.1*Cos[\[Pi]/L*x]}, u, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

which gives me

> NDSolve::delpde:Delay partial differential equations are not currently supported by NDSolve"

The warning is understandable because the function `u[xp, t]` is still unknow when `NIntegrate` is evaluated. Note that we should use `PrincipalValue` here in `NIntegrate` because there is a singularity at $x=xp$, which has been specified in the integration range.

Comment: The method I used to solve the earlier problem cited in the question cannot be employed here, because the PDE is nonlinear.  It may, however, be possible to solve the equation using the method outlined [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html#1699661144), although not without a great deal of effort.

Comment: My answer to [question 175080](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175178/1063) may be helpful, although it is a bit simpler.

Comment: If you solve this problem, please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Perhaps, I can try near the end of the week, if you have not already done so.

Comment: I think it would be advisable to change the order of `D[NIntegrate[...]]` to `NIntegrate[D[...]]`. This would mean replacing `D[Integrate[u[xp, t]*Cot[\[Pi] (x - xp)/(2*L)], {xp, -L, L}], {x, 3}]` with `NIntegrate[-((\[Pi]^3 (2 + Cos[(\[Pi] (x - xp))/L]) Csc[(\[Pi] (x - xp))/(2 L)]^4 u[xp, t])/(4 L^3)), {xp, -L, L}]`, where the integrand in the second form was found with `D[u[xp, t]*Cot[\[Pi] (x - xp)/(2*L)], {x, 3}] // FullSimplify`.

Comment: Numerical derivatives are terrible, they are unstable and prone to noise. Avoid whenever possible. Here it's possible, so I'd advise to avoid them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation

Comment: There is a typo in line usum = dUdxxx[t].Cot[\[Pi](midxtab - xtab)/(2*L)*h;.   Where the closing shall be palace. Your could have use the update as an answer to your own  problem

Comment: @JoseEnriqueCalderon Thanks. I have corrected the typo.

Comment: Do you feel that the problem now is solved?  If so, you could actually compute the solution and post it as an answer.  If not, what do you need help with?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I now can provide a solution to my question. Please feel free to correct me. I will never accept my answer before you post yours when you have time to write it up. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the integral blow up when `x` is equal to an end point `±L`?  There is no principal value there.  I take it though that `u[x, t]` is to be periodic in `x` and if we shift the interval of integration, the principal value would become well-defined.  Is that correct and what you want?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Frankly speaking, i am not sure if i have understood your questions. In my original question, I use `PrincipalValue` to avoid a singularity at `x=xp`. In the answer, `M=40` corresponds to the time-integrating _line_ along `+L` (right end of a periodic interval).  If the integral is discretized at mid-points, it appears not to blow up. Thus there seems no need of principal value in the current method. Yes, `u[x,t]` is periodic in `x`. The periodicity has been imposed through the derivatives near the ends of an interval, and thus the solution at `-L` is the same as that of `+L`.

Comment: In your `NIntegrate` call, when `x == L`, say, you're integrating over `-L <= xp <= L`, you can't find the principal value because you only have half of the singularity. The part where `x > L`, which would cancel out the part where `x < L` in the principal value sense, is not integrated. Compare `NIntegrate[Cot[t], {t, 0, Pi, Pi}, Method -> "PrincipalValue"]` with `NIntegrate[Cot[t], {t, 2, Pi, 2 + Pi}, Method -> "PrincipalValue", AccuracyGoal -> 100]`. If we can shift the integration domain because the integrand is periodic, then I have a solution.

Answer (score 10):

Based on the hacky way I used in [my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175080/integrating-over-x-in-numerically-solving-a-partial-integrodifferential-equati?noredirect=1&lq=1); I had to split up the `NDSolve` process, so as not to redefine `MapThread` too soon:

```
L = 10; tmax = 2;
sys = {D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x] + D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + 
     D[u[x, t], {x, 4}] + 1/(2 L)*int[D[u[x, t], {x, 3}], x, t] == 0, 
   u[-L, t] == u[L, t], u[x, 0] == 0.1*Cos[\[Pi]/L*x]};
periodize[data_] := Append[data, {N@L, data[[1, 2]]}]; (* for periodic interpolation *)
Block[{int},
  (* the integral *)
  int[uppp_, x_?NumericQ, t_ /; t == 0] := (cnt++;
    NIntegrate[
     D[0.1*Cos[\[Pi]/L*xp], {xp, 3}]*Cot[\[Pi] (x - xp)/(2*L)],
     {xp, x - L, x, x + L}, 
     Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", Method -> "PrincipalValue"},
     PrecisionGoal -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> 20]);
  int[uppp_?VectorQ, xv_?VectorQ, t_] := Function[x,
     cnt++;
     NIntegrate[
      Interpolation[periodize@Transpose@{xv, uppp}, xp, 
        PeriodicInterpolation -> True]*Cot[\[Pi] (x - xp)/(2*L)],
      {xp, x - L, x, x + L}, 
      Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", Method -> "PrincipalValue"},
      PrecisionGoal -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 20] (* adjust to suit *)
     ] /@ xv;
  (* monitor while integrating pde *)
  Clear[foo];
  cnt = 0;
  PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{foo, cnt, Clock[Infinity]};
  (* broken down NDSolve call *)
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{MapThread},
   {state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[sys, u, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
     StepMonitor :> (foo = t)];
   Unprotect[MapThread];
   MapThread[f_, data_, 1] /; ! FreeQ[f, int] := f @@ data;
   Protect[MapThread];
   NDSolve`Iterate[state, {0, tmax}];
   sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state]
   ]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[u[x, t] /. sol, {x, -10.`, 10.`}, {t, 0.`, 2.`}]
```

[image]

With the settings `PrecisionGoal -> 4, MaxRecursion -> 9` in the `NIntegrate`, it takes the same amount of time and does more integrations.  Breaking down the `NDSolve` process is explained in the tutorial [Components and Data Structures](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html).

Comment: Very impressive (+1).  Thanks.

Comment: @Michael E2, your method is cool and far outside of my knowledge range about mma. Could you explain a little the reason `Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", Method... }` in `NIntegrate`. I quickly go through _tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies_, and found the general specification `NIntegrate[f[x],{x,a,b,c}, Method->{"PrincipalValue",Method->methodspec,"SingularPointIntegrationRadius"->\[Epsilon]}]`, which appears to be different from yours. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: By testing the code as it is, i encounter the usual warning: >NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. I don't understand the issue because the singular point has been specified. Please give me suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user55777 [Some posts concerning "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=InterpolationPointsSubdivision) shows use-cases, but it's not well documented. Basically, interpolating functions have (weak) singularities at the interpolation points (nodes), and integration rules are more effective on intervals over which functions do not have singularities.  By dividing up the interval of integration at the interpolation points, convergence is more easily obtained. It can be inefficient if there are a lot of interpolation points.

Comment: Technically, it is a preprocessor "strategy" and so can take another `Method` argument, which may be another "strategy" or "rule."  See [NIntegrate Introduction, Strategies, Rules, and Preprocessors](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntroduction.html#118305364)

Comment: @user55777 `NIntegrate::slwcon` is just a warning and can often be ignored when not followed by another error. On a well-behaved integral, `NIntegrate` expects the error to converge to the precision/accuracy goals at a certain, probably heuristic, rate.  As a result, integrating functions with singularities such as interpolating functions usually converge more slowly and sometimes trigger the warning.

Comment: @user55777 I'm afraid I don't know what to suggest.  It seems it would depend on which definitions are saved and whether some definitions have been cleared.

Comment: @user55777  The method I thought would work no longer appears to, and my back-up approach is very similar to yours.  I suggest that you add to your answer a plot of the result you obtain, and then accept the answer, if any, that looks correct to you.  I shall try again later to solve this question, but I have little time at the moment.  So, please do not wait for me.

Comment: @MichaelE2 why did u Block `iint` and `xx`, which did not appear in the expression subsequently?

Comment: @jsxs They are probably a remnant of testing/development. I must have forgotten to remove them from Block[].  I can only remember that int[] was a wrapper for iint[] but I either solved some programming problem of setting up the NIntegrate[] or changed the approach. There was a problem but I’ve forgotten what it was

Comment: @MichaelE2 sorry for troubling you. In the 1st `int[u_, ...]`, `u` hasn't been used in the function, why did u introduce it there? Could u have a look at the `intnest` my [recent post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202230/speed-up-ndsolve-for-an-integro-differential-equation?noredirect=1#comment522836_202230). I am not sure if I did a correct extension. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @user55777 The function `int[]` is called in `sys` with three arguments. At the initial condition at `t == 0`, we can compute the integral from the initial condition and ignore `u`.  I think the confusion is that the pattern `u_` in the defintion of `int[]` has nothing to do with the function `u[x, t]` in `sys`. It's really the 3rd derivative of `u` (w.r.t. `x`). I should have called it `uppp_` as in the second definition. It won't change how the code works, but it's better style to use variable names that reflect the meaning of the variable.  Will update.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The combination of `NIntegrate` and `Interpolation` makes the integration very slow, i.e., `NIntegrate[Interpolation[periodize@Transpose@{xv, uppp}, xp, PeriodicInterpolation -> True]*Cot[\[Pi] (x - xp)/(2*L)], {xp, x - L, x, x + L}, ...]`. Is it possible to avoid using the `Interpolation`?

Comment: @user55777 (1) You could subtract `u0*Cot[\[Pi] (x - xp)/(2*L)]` from the integrand, where `u0` is the value of the interpolation at `xp == x`. Then you don't need the principal value method, which numerically approximates a limit (probably slowly). (2) You could try to come up with an integration rule.  The integrand between the grid points has the form of a cubic polynomial times the `Cot[]`.  Then you can bypass the overhead of `NIntegrate` and `Interpolation`. That might require some considerable work, though.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I didn't understand your first suggestion. Did you mean I should use `NIntegrate[(D[u[xp, 0], {xp, 3}]-u[xp, 0])*Cot[\[Pi] (x - xp)/(2*L)], {xp, x - L, x, x + L}]`. Could you please give an update?

Comment: @user55777 Sorry, I'm rather busy and haven't had time to investigate. Re (1): Your integral has the form $\int _{x-L}^{L+x}f(x_p)\cot(\pi(x-x_p)/(2 L))dx_p$. We have  $\int _{x-L}^{L+x}f(x)\cot(\pi(x-x_p)/(2 L))dx_p=0$ (PV). If we subtract it from your integral, we get  $\int _{x-L}^{L+x}[f(x_p)-f(x)]\cot(\pi(x-x_p)/(2 L))dx_p$, which no longer has a singularity at $x_p=x$. It should speed up the integration a bit.

Comment: Re (2): `Interpolation` by default returns a piecewise cubic interpolation. Over each interpolating interval $f(x_p)$ is equal to a cubic polynomial. One might be able to take advantage of it. The trapezoid rule might work well, in fact, on the desingularized integrand in the previous comment. (The integrand still has weak singularities at the interpolation nodes, so it might not be that accurate.)

Answer (score 4):

After studying during these days, now I could answer the question myself.
I admit that both my solution and code are far from good and efficient, even some mistakes or making an unnecessary move. Please give your suggestion if you see anything.

We first create $2M$ equidistant grid points $x_m=(m-M)h$ with $m=1,2,...,2M$.
The x-position of the grid points is stored in `xtab`:

```
M = 40; L = 10; h = L/M;
xtab = Table[(m - M) h, {m, 1, 2*M}];
```

Then we should discretize the solution of PDE along $x$ into $2M$ solutions of a set of coupled ODEs. `u[m][t]` denotes the solution of function $u(x,t)$ at point $x_m$. Here, I didn't include the left end-point, since it can be set to be `u[0][t]=u[2*M][t]` according to the periodicity.

```
U[t_] = Table[u[m][t], {m, 1, 2*M}];
```

The spatial derivatives are discretized using 2nd-order central differences,
here the periodic condition should be applied.
**Because I didn't know how to generate these derivatives using `ListCorrelate` both for boundary points and internal points in one-line command, I manually add the derivatives near the boundary.** Please give me some advice if you know how to do this.

1st-derivative wrt `x`:

```
internaldUdx = ListCorrelate[{-1, 0, 1}/(2 h), U[t]]; (* for 2<= m <= 19*)
dUdx = Join[{(u[2][t] - u[2*M][t])/(2 h)}, 
internaldUdx, {(u[1][t] - u[2*M - 1][t])/(2 h)}];
```

2nd-derivative wrt `x`:

```
internaldUdxx = ListCorrelate[{1, -2, 1}/h^2, U[t]]; (* for 2<= m<=19 *)
dUdxx = Join[{(u[2][t] - 2*u[1][t] + u[2*M][t])/h^2}, 
internaldUdxx, {(u[1][t] - 2 u[2*M][t] + u[2*M - 1][t])/h^2}];
```

3rd-derivative wrt `x`

```
internaldUdxxx = ListCorrelate[{-1, 2, 0, -2, 1}/(2 h^3), U[t]]; (*for 3<= m <= 2*M-2*)
dUdxxx = Join[{(-u[2 M - 1][t] + 2 u[2 M][t] - 2 u[2][t] + u[3][t])/(2 h^3), (-u[2*M][t] + 2 u[1][t] - 2 u[3][t] + u[4][t])/(2 h^3)}, 
internaldUdxxx, {(-u[2*M - 1 - 2][t] + 2*u[2*M - 1 - 1][t] - 2*u[2*M - 1 + 1][t] + u[1][t])/(2 h^3), (-u[2*M - 2][t] + 2 u[2*M - 1][t] - 2 u[1][t] + u[2][t])/(2 h^3)}];
```

4th-derivative wrt `x`:

```
internaldUdxxxx = ListCorrelate[{1, -4, 6, -4, 1}/h^4, U[t]]; (*for 3 <= m <= 2M-2*)
dUdxxxx = Join[{(u[2*M - 1][t] - 4*u[2*M][t] + 6*u[1][t] - 4*u[1 + 1][t] + 
 u[1 + 2][t])/h^4, (u[2*M][t] - 4*u[1][t] + 6*u[2][t] - 4*u[2 + 1][t] + u[2 + 2][t])/h^4}, 
internaldUdxxxx, {(u[2*M - 3][t] - 4*u[2*M - 2][t] + 6*u[2*M - 1][t] - 4*u[2*M][t] + u[1][t])/h^4, (u[2*M - 2][t] - 4*u[2*M - 1][t] + 6*u[2*M][t] - 4 u[1][t] + u[2][t])/h^4}];
```

To discretize the integral, we may introduce the mid-points: $x_{m+1/2}=(x_m+x_{m+1})/2$ for $m=1,2,....,2M-1$ with $x_{1/2}=(-L+x_1)/2$.

```
midxtab = Join[{(-L + (1 - M) h)/2}, Table[((m - M) h + (m + 1 - M) h)/2, {m, 1, 2*M - 1}]];
int[midP_] := h/(2 L)*dUdxxxIntP.Cot[\[Pi]*(midxtab[[midP]] - xtab)/(2*L)]
```

Constructing the system of ODEs and the discrete initial condition:

```
eqns = Thread[D[U[t], t] == -U[t]*dUdx - dUdxx - dUdxxxx - 
 Join[Table[1/2*(int[midP] + int[midP + 1]), {midP, 1, 2*M - 1}], {int[2*M] + int[1]}]];

initc = Thread[U[0] == 1/10*Cos[\[Pi]/L*xtab]];
```

The original PDE now can be solved numerically:

```
tmax = 10;

lines = NDSolveValue[{eqns, initc}, U[t], {t, 0, tmax},
Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"}] // Flatten;
```

Then, we can plot by interpolating (appreciating @bbgodfrey's answer to a [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175080/integrating-over-x-in-numerically-solving-a-partial-integrodifferential-equati/175178#175178))

```
surf = Flatten[Table[{(line - M)*h, t, lines[[line]]}, {line, 1, 2*M}, {t, 0, 
 tmax, 0.2}], 1];

ListPlot3D[surf, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "u"}, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

Comment: You did not use `PrincipalValue`, although you indicated that you should use.

Comment: Parameter is not defined `dUdxxxIntP`.

Answer (score 3):

We can use iterations. The code is simple but takes time.

```
L = 10; tmax = 2; del = 10^-6; dx = (L - del)/6 - del;
n = 5;
int[0][x_, t_] := 0
Do[U[i] = 
  NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x] + 
      D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, t], {x, 4}] + 
      1/(2 L)*int[i - 1][x, t] == 0, u[-L, t] == u[L, t], 
    u[x, 0] == 0.1*Cos[\[Pi]/L*x]}, u, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "MinPoints" -> 137}}}]; 
 int[i] = Interpolation[
   Flatten[ParallelTable[{{x, t}, 
      NIntegrate[
       Derivative[3, 0][U[i]][xp, t]*
        Cot[\[Pi] (x - xp)/(2*L)], {xp, -L, x, L}, 
       Method -> "PrincipalValue"]}, {x, -L + del, L - del, dx}, {t, 
      0, tmax, .2*tmax}], 1]];, {i, 1, n}]


Table[Plot3D[U[i][x, t], {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax}], {i, 1, n}]
Table[Plot3D[
  int[i][x, t] - int[i - 1][x, t], {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  PlotRange -> All], {i, 1, n}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: thank you. I found that with the same conditions, your code is much faster than Michael's. Could I consult you three questions: 1. what determine the choice of `n = 5`? I consider it as an iterator for the calculation of integral, but didn't see a convergence criterion; 2. you actually use FD in `x`?; 3. Does `Table[Plot3D[U[i][x, t], {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax}], {i, 1, n}]` only give the intermediate solutions. But how can i plot a _convergent_ `u[x,t]` with something like `Plot3D[u[x, t]/.finalsol, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax}]`?

Comment: `U[i][x, t]` this is a solution to the equation at each iteration `i`. The final solution of the equation `U[n][x, t]` depends on the selected error.

Comment: In this example, only convergence is shown. You can add a line of code outside the loop using `int[n][x, t]` to calculate `finalsol`.