# Numerical solution of a singular integral equation

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations, approximation

I am looking to approximate the solution `u` of the following equation using discretization method or any other idea. Is there any way on how to find a numerical solution for it:

`u[t]-Integrate[Abs[t - s]^(-1/2)*u[s], {s, 0, 1}] == 1/3 (-2 Sqrt[1 - t]+3t-4 Sqrt[1-t]t-4t^(3/2))` where `0<t<1.`

The solution is `u[x]=x` but I am assuming that I dont know the answer and we need to find approximation for it.

Comment: Either you need to provide the function `u[t]`, or you need to provide an equation that `u[t]` satisfies.

Comment: In fact, I need to find this `u` numerically.

Comment: The above is not valid Mathematica code? In Mathematica a function `u(t)` is written as `u[t]` also for `u(s)` it is `u[s]`

Comment: Perhaps you meant you need to solve `u[t] - Integrate[Abs[t-s]^(-1/2) u[s], {s, 0, 1}] == 0` numerically. If there is no equation, then there is no way to solve for `u[t]`.

Comment: I have corrected the question accordingly

Comment: If an approximation is fine, you could write $u(t)=a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+\mathcal O(t^3)$ and solve for $a_i$. I get $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$, $a_2=0$, etc, which confirms that $u(t)=t$ is a solution.

Comment: Some times the solution is not a polynomial

Comment: Maybe a good start would be to go to [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com) and ask: given a function $u(t)$ for $t\in[0,1]$, how can we best describe the function $w(t)=\int_0^1 ds\,u(s)/\sqrt{\lvert s-t\rvert}$ for $t\in[0,1]$? Once you know more properties of this transformed function, your problem may be easier to reflect in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a general solution that works by interpolation. I'll present the method in a very slow way, and we can work on speeding it up later on if desired.

First, we make an *ansatz* for the function $u(t)$ on the interval $[0,1]$. Here I use a grid of $n+1$ equidistant points and a linear interpolation scheme:

```
n = 10;
tvalues = Subdivide[n];
uvalues = Unique[] & /@ tvalues;  (* we don't care what these variables are called *)
tupairs = Transpose[{tvalues, uvalues}];
u[t_] = Piecewise@BlockMap[{((t-#[[2,1]])#[[1,2]]-(t-#[[1,1]])#[[2,2]])/(#[[1, 1]]-#[[2, 1]]),
          #[[1,1]]<=t<=#[[2,1]]}&, tupairs, 2, 1]
```

Check that this interpolation scheme has indeed the values `uvalues` on the grid points `tvalues`:

```
u /@ tvalues == uvalues
(* True *)
```

Define the integral $\int_0^1 ds\,u(s)/\sqrt{\lvert t-s\rvert}$:

```
uint[t_] := Integrate[u[s]/Sqrt[Abs[t-s]], {s, 0, 1}]
```

Evaluate this integral on the same grid of `tvalues`: here is the slow part of this calculation, and could probably be sped up dramatically,

```
uintvalues = uint /@ tvalues
(* long output where every element is a linear combination of the uvalues *)
```

The right-hand side of the integral equation, evaluated on the same grid of `tvalues`:

```
f[t_] = 1/3 (-2 Sqrt[1 - t] + 3 t - 4 Sqrt[1 - t] t - 4 t^(3/2));
fvalues = f /@ tvalues
(* long output *)
```

Solve for the coefficients of $u(t)$: a linear system of equations for the grid values `uvalues`, found by setting the left and right sides of the integral equation equal at every grid point in `tvalues`,

```
solution = tupairs /.
  First@Solve[Thread[uvalues - uintvalues == fvalues] // N, uvalues]
```

> {{0, 5.84947*10^-16}, {1/10, 0.1}, {1/5, 0.2}, {3/10, 0.3}, {2/5, 0.4}, {1/2, 0.5}, {3/5, 0.6}, {7/10, 0.7}, {4/5, 0.8}, {9/10, 0.9}, {1, 1.}}

This confirms your analytic solution $u(t)=t$ but is much more general.

You don't need the `// N` in the last step if you prefer an analytic solution; however, numerical solution is very much faster.

```
ListLinePlot[solution, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

## Update: much faster version

To speed up this algorithm, the main point is to speed up the calculation of the `uintvalues` from the `uvalues`. Instead of doing piecewise integrals, this calculation can be expressed as a matrix multiplication, `uintvalues == X.uvalues`, with the matrix `X` defined as

```
n = 10;
X = N[4/(3 Sqrt[n])]*
  SparseArray[{{1,1} -> 1.,
               {-1,-1} -> 1.,
               Band[{2,2}, {-2,-2}] -> 2.,
               Band[{2,1}, {-1,1}, {1,0}] ->
                 N@Table[(i-2)^(3/2)-(i-1)^(3/2)+3/2*(i-1)^(1/2), {i,2,n+1}],
               Band[{1,-1}, {-2,-1}, {1,0}] -> N@Reverse@Table[(i-2)^(3/2)-(i-1)^(3/2)+3/2*(i-1)^(1/2), {i,2,n+1}],
               Sequence @@ Table[Band[{1,a}, {1+n-a,n}] -> N[a^(3/2)-2*(a-1)^(3/2)+(a-2)^(3/2)], {a,2,n}],
               Sequence @@ Table[Band[{a+1,2}, {n+1,n+2-a}] -> N[a^(3/2)-2(a-1)^(3/2)+(a-2)^(3/2)], {a,2,n}]},
              {n+1, n+1}] // Normal;
```

(The coefficients follow from the `Piecewise` *ansatz* and analytic integration.)

With this matrix defined, the algorithm becomes simply

```
tvalues = Subdivide[n];
f[t_] = 1/3 (-2 Sqrt[1 - t] + 3 t - 4 Sqrt[1 - t] t - 4 t^(3/2));
fvalues = f /@ tvalues;
solution = Inverse[IdentityMatrix[n+1] - X].fvalues
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{tvalues, solution}]]
```

In this way, $n=1000$ grid points can be achieved in a few seconds, most of which is still spent in assembling the `X`-matrix. The next step would be to write down a faster way of assembling `X`.

Comment: Dear Roman, I couldn't find any word that deserve saying Thank you for the idea you provided. The solution works perfectly for me. We just need to work to speed it up. Also I have another schemes that I need to discuss it with you. Please send me your email. I need someone to work with me on a paid project if you interested.

Comment: You're welcome. Email me at `Uncompress["1:eJxTTMoPChZnYGAoys9NzNMrTs7IzUxNcSjNy0xKLNZLzgAAnn0Kkg=="]`

Comment: @Roman How did you find the interpolation `u[t]`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev every piece of the `Piecewise` function is a two-point [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). Concretely, if you set `f[x_] = y1*(x - x2)/(x1 - x2) + y2*(x - x1)/(x2 - x1)`, then `f[x1] == y1` and `f[x2] == y2`. In this way the function `f` passes through the two points `{x1,y1}` and `{x2,y2}`.

Comment: @Roman Now I see why the solution of the equation coincides with the exact one.

Comment: @AlexTrounev yes the linear interpolation perfectly represents a linear solution :-) However this method can be used with other kinds of interpolations too (cubic splines, for example). And the linear interpolation will approximate nonlinear solutions pretty well too. I just picked the simplest way to get started.

Comment: @ Roman I am just wondering how do you ended up by the form of X from the Integral eqn?

Comment: @Mutaz by calculating `X = D[uintvalues, {uvalues}]` for several values of `n` and then looking for patterns.

Comment: @Roman, can i understand the 3rd lines of the 1st code block as follows? 1. With `Unique[]&/@tvalues` you are applying `Unique[]&` to `{0,1/10,2/10,...,9/10,1}`, where `Unique[]&` is a pure function. If correct, but why the pure function has no formal parameter? I thought that any pure function should have its formal parameter. 2. I just learned that `Unique[]` is used to generate a new unique symbol named $x. You said "not care what the variables are called". But if it is necessary?

Comment: @jsxs 1. Correct. All I wanted here is a list of symbols that has the right length. `Unique[]&` is a pure function with zero arguments (which is perfectly legal), and so the supplied argument in `Map` is discarded. I agree it's a bit opaque; I could have done `uvalues = Table[Unique[], {n+1}]` instead for more clarity.

Comment: @jsxs 2. You can pick any list of `uvalues` you like, as long as it has the correct length of `n+1`. You could for example build a list with `uvalues = Table[ToExpression["u" <> ToString[i]], {i, 0, n}]` so that the variables have more meaningful names. Or you could use subscripting like `uvalues = Table[Subscript[u, i], {i, 0, n}]` or indexing like `uvalues = Array[u, n + 1]`. It really doesn't matter, as these variable names aren't used anywhere and the `solution` appears without them.

Comment: @Roman thanks for the clarification. I prefer to `uvalues = Table[Unique[], {n+1}]`, which should be more transparent to beginner, like me :-). Btw, key point to me: for a pure function without argument, the supplied argument in `Map` will be discarded **partially** with the number of elements retained to take effect.

Comment: @jsxs yes this method is very general. The "much faster version" section is different for different integrals though. You're welcome!

Comment: @Roman I have tried to understand and combine your method with Michael's answer to my post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192123/solving-an-integro-differential-equation-with-mathematica/192736?noredirect=1#comment503601_192736. It includes an integral `int` with a singular point. The code is slow for large integration time `tmax`. Could you help with speeding it up. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @user55777 please contact me at `Uncompress["1:eJxTTMoPChZnYGAoys9NzNMrTs7IzUxNcSjNy0xKLNZLzgAAnn0Kkg=="]`

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, only an idea to solve the problem.

I tried to solve your integral equation iterativ  using NestList:

```
sol = NestList[
Function[fu,
FunctionInterpolation[
 1/3 (-2 Sqrt[1 - t] + 3 t - 4 t Sqrt[1 - t] - 4 t^(3/2)) + 
  NIntegrate[fu[s]/Sqrt[Sqrt[(t - s)^2]] , {s, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> "LocalAdaptive" ], {t, 0, 1 }]
] , 0 &,  (* initial function *)5];
```

Unfortunately the Picarditeration doesn't converge in your case:

```
    Plot[Map[#[t] &, sol], {t, 0, 1}
```

[image]

Perhaps you have additional system knowhow to force a convergent iteration?

Comment: tried other starting point perhaps? e.g., `#&` is the exact solution, so a fixed point presumably (is the system stable?)

Comment: I tried this Initial function too but  fixpoint isn't stable

Answer (score 3):

I will add another method that is not as accurate as method @Roman, but faster.  It uses expression describing the integral `Integrate[1/Sqrt[Abs[t-s]], {s, 0, 1}]`

```
ker[s_, t_] := If[t > s, -2*Sqrt[t - s], 2*Sqrt[s - t]]
```

Then everything is as usual

```
np = 51; points = fun = Table[Null, {np}];
Table[points[[i]] = i/np, {i, np}];
sol = Unique[] & /@ points;

Do[fun[[i]] = 
   1/3 (-2 Sqrt[1 - t] + 3 t - 4 Sqrt[1 - t] t - 4 t^(3/2)) /. 
    t -> points[[i]], {i, np}];

sol1 = sol /. 
   First@Solve[
     Table[sol[[j]] - 
        Sum[.5*(sol[[i]] + 
            sol[[i + 1]])*(ker[points[[i + 1]], points[[j]]] - 
            ker[points[[i]], points[[j]]]), {i, 1, np - 1}] == 
       fun[[j]], {j, 1, np}], sol];

u = Transpose[{points, sol1}];

Show[Plot[t, {t, 0, 1}], ListPlot[u]]
```

[image: Fig1]