# Solving PDE and avoiding singularity

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, singularity

I have the following question about solving a PDE:

```
L = 7 (*domain size*); a=4; b=2;
d = 10.6455; e = 0.90998; (*to be adjusted*)
c = 1/10; (*small parameter in initial condition*)

sys = {D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x] - D[u[x, t], {x, 2}]
       + D[u[x, t], {x, 4}] + a*1/(2 L)*int[D[u[x, t], {x, 3}], x, t]
       - d*D[u[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x], x] + b*e*D[u[x, t], {x, 3}] == 0,
       u[-L, t] == u[L, t], u[x, 0] == c*Cos[(\[Pi]*x)/L]};
```

The method to solve the PDE is a slight modification of [@Michael E2's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/192736/55777). **Note: to reproduce the error, please try `nGrid = 31`, the computation will finish in about 1100s with a singularity at `t=0.478698`.**

```
periodize[data_] := Append[data, {N@L, data[[1, 2]]}];(*for periodic interpolation*)

tmax = 10; nGrid = 31(*91*);
inicos[x_] = c Cos[(\[Pi]*x)/L];

Block[{int}, int[u_, x_?NumericQ, t_ /; t == 0] := (cnt++;
    NIntegrate[inicos'''[xp]*Cot[\[Pi] (x - xp)/(2*L)], {xp, x - L, x, x + L}, 
     Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", Method -> "PrincipalValue"},
     PrecisionGoal -> 8, AccuracyGoal -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 10]);
  int[uppp_?VectorQ, xv_?VectorQ, t_?NumericQ] := Function[x, cnt++;
     NIntegrate[Interpolation[periodize@Transpose@{xv, uppp}, xp, 
        PeriodicInterpolation -> True]*Cot[\[Pi] (x - xp)/(2*L)], {xp, x - L, x, x + L},
      Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", Method -> "PrincipalValue"},
      PrecisionGoal -> 8, AccuracyGoal -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 10]] /@xv;
  (*monitor while integrating pde*)
  Clear[foo];
  cnt = 0;
  PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{foo, cnt, Clock[Infinity]};
  (*broken down NDSolve call*)
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{MapThread},
   {state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[sys, u, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax},
     Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> nGrid, "MaxPoints" -> nGrid, 
         "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}(*, Method\[Rule]{"StiffnessSwitching",
       "NonstiffTest"\[Rule]Automatic}*)}, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, 
     (*WorkingPrecision -> 20,*) MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], 
     StepMonitor :> (foo = t)];
   Unprotect[MapThread];
   MapThread[f_, data_, 1] /; ! FreeQ[f, int] := f @@ data;
   Protect[MapThread];
   NDSolve`Iterate[state, {0, tmax}];
   sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state]]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

When solving the equation, I always got the following error:

> NDSolve`Iterate::ndsz: At t == ...., step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

Actually, you will see a series of warnings, such as `slwcon` and `ncvb`, which could be ignored (please see Michael's comments in the above link). In addition, I also got the warning

> Warning: estimated initial error on the specified spatial grid in the direction of independent variable x exceeds prescribed error tolerance.

By increasing `nGrid` from `31` up to `91`, the warning remains. However, I think this is not that serious.

**Summary of my trial:**

1. With `nGrid = 91` as above, the singularity occurs at `t=0.7289`. Observe the solution at the final moment.

   ```
   Plot[{Evaluate[u[x, 0] /. sol], Evaluate[u[x, 0.7289] /. sol]}, {x, -L, L}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-L, L}, All}, ImageSize -> 400, PlotPoints -> 60, 
   AspectRatio -> 0.5, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}]
   ```

[image]

2. With `d=10.4187`, `e=0.639919`, and `nGrid = 31` (faster computation), the singularity occurs earlier at `t=0.5019`. I plotted the solution at the final moment.

[image]

3. I also tried `nGrid = 46` with `Method\[Rule]{"StiffnessSwitching", "NonstiffTest"\[Rule]Automatic}`, but the singularity error remains at about `t=0.86`. The solutions at the finial moment are similar to the above plots. For example, with `nGrid = 46`, singular time `t=0.8554`, the solution is as follows:
   [image]

We can see that the fluctuations in the solution are concentrated in a small interval and that it doesn't seem to have developed a real singularity (since its amplitudes are still acceptable physically).

Based on this observation, to deploy as many as possible points to resolve the *local* solution, I tried to use a one-order smaller domain of `L=0.7` with `d=2.14617`, `e=-9.20831`. Now `NDSolve` can run up to `tmax = 50` without singularity using either `nGrid = 46` or `31`. But the solution is always a straight line close to zero, which I don't know why.

[image]

**The question:**

I understand that the PDE might have a singularity for some values of the parameters. I also found that the term `- d*D[u[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x], x]` should be the reason for the singularity because when this term is removed this equation can be solved.

I just try to find somehow a well-behaved solution, which can develop up to a large time, say, `tmax=50`, with a proper set of parameters' values. I prefer to adjust firstly `L`, `d` and `e`. Please give me some suggestions on how to adjust the parameters and/or correct the code to avoid the singularity. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The integral term cannot influence the solution of the equation as much as in your code. Put `int = 0`, we get a smooth solution. This smooth solution should be used in computing `int`, as in my answer. Then we get a slight change in the smooth solution. But direct use of `int` produces numerical instability (it can be easily proved).

Answer (score 1):

Using my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192123/solving-an-integro-differential-equation-with-mathematica/192722#192722) I suggest abandoning the author code. My code immediately gives a realistic answer. Firstly, we normalize the interval `x` by `2 L`. Secondly, we normalize the time by `u0/(2 L)` with `u0 = 1`. Therefore, here we solve the equation in dimensional units on `{x,-7,7},{t,0,28}`.

```
L = 1/2; tmax = 2; del = 
 10^-6; dx = (L - del)/6 - del; L0 = 14 (*domain size*); a = 4; b = 2;
d = 10.6455; e = 0.90998;(*to be adjusted*)c = 
 1/10;(*small parameter in initial condition*)
n = 5;
int[0][x_, t_] := 0
Do[U[i] = 
  NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x] - 
      D[u[x, t], {x, 2}]/L0 + D[u[x, t], {x, 4}]/L0^3 + 
      a/(2 L0^2)*int[i - 1][x, t] - d*D[u[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x], x]/L0 +
       b*e*D[u[x, t], {x, 3}]/L0^2 == 0, u[-L, t] == u[L, t], 
    u[x, 0] == c Cos[\[Pi]/L*x]}, u, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "MinPoints" -> 137, "MaxPoints" -> 137, 
         "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}}];
 int[i] = 
  Interpolation[
   Flatten[ParallelTable[{{x, t}, 
      NIntegrate[
        Derivative[3, 0][U[i]][xp, t]*
         Cot[\[Pi] (x - xp)/(2*L)], {xp, -L, x, L}, 
        Method -> "PrincipalValue"] // Quiet}, {x, -L + del, L - del, 
      dx}, {t, 0, tmax, .2*tmax}], 1]];, {i, 1, n}]
```

The process converges quickly. There are no singularities, no stiffness,this is a completely smooth solution.

```
Table[Plot3D[U[i][x, t], {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, Mesh -> None, 
       ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
       AxesLabel -> Automatic] // Quiet, {i, 1, n}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Take the author’s code, put `int[] = 0`, in a second we get the first picture in Fig. 1. Therefore, all the problems of this code are related to `int[]`.

```
L = 1/2; tmax = 2; del = 
 10^-6; dx = (L - del)/6 - 
  del; L0 = 14 (*domain size*); a = 4; b = 2; L1 = L - 10^-6;
d = 10.6455; e = 0.90998;(*to be adjusted*)c = 
 1/10;(*small parameter in initial condition*)

sys = {D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x] - D[u[x, t], {x, 2}]/L0 +
      D[u[x, t], {x, 4}]/L0^3 - d*D[u[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x], x]/L0 + 
     b*e*D[u[x, t], {x, 3}]/L0^2 == 0, u[-L, t] == u[L, t], 
   u[x, 0] == c*Cos[(\[Pi]*x)/L]};

periodize[data_] := 
 Append[data, {N@L, 
   data[[1, 
    2]]}];(*for periodic interpolation*)tmax = 2; nGrid = 137(*91*);


inicos[x_] = c Cos[(\[Pi]*x)/L];

Block[{int}, int[u_, x_?NumericQ, t_ /; t == 0] := (cnt++;
    NIntegrate[inicos'''[xp]*Cot[\[Pi] (x - xp)/(2*L)], {xp, x - L, x, x + L}, 
     Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", Method -> "PrincipalValue"},
     PrecisionGoal -> 8, AccuracyGoal -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 10]);
  int[uppp_?VectorQ, xv_?VectorQ, t_?NumericQ] := Function[x, cnt++;
     NIntegrate[Interpolation[periodize@Transpose@{xv, uppp}, xp, 
        PeriodicInterpolation -> True]*Cot[\[Pi] (x - xp)/(2*L)], {xp, x - L, x, x + L},
      Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", Method -> "PrincipalValue"},
      PrecisionGoal -> 8, AccuracyGoal -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 10]] /@xv;
     (*monitor while integrating pde*)Clear[foo];
     cnt = 0;
     PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{foo, cnt, Clock[Infinity]};
     (*broken down NDSolve call*)
     Internal`InheritedBlock[{MapThread}, {state} = 
       NDSolve`ProcessEquations[sys, u, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
        Method -> { 
          "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
            "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
              "MinPoints" -> 137, "MaxPoints" -> 137, 
              "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}}, StepMonitor :> (foo = t)];
      Unprotect[MapThread];
      MapThread[f_, data_, 1] /; ! FreeQ[f, int] := f @@ data;
      Protect[MapThread];
      NDSolve`Iterate[state, {0, tmax}];
      sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state]]]
    Plot3D[u[x, t] /. sol, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
     ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Finally, we consider equation `sys = {D[u[x, t], t] + a*1/(2 L)*int[D[u[x, t], {x, 3}], x, t]/L0^2 ==0, u[-L, t] == u[L, t], u[x, 0] == c*Cos[(\[Pi]*x)/L]};` to establish how this integral behaves. After 4 hours of waiting, I received these wonderful pictures. We see that the solution increases exponentially as `Exp[1000 t]`. This is the main cause of instability.

```
L = 1/2; tmax = 2; del = 
 10^-6; dx = (L - del)/6 - del; L0 = 14 (*domain size*); a = 4; b = 2;
d = 10.6455; e = 0.90998;(*to be adjusted*)c = 
 1/10;(*small parameter in initial condition*)

sys = {D[u[x, t], t] + a*1/(2 L)*int[D[u[x, t], {x, 3}], x, t]/L0^2 ==
     0, u[-L, t] == u[L, t], u[x, 0] == c*Cos[(\[Pi]*x)/L]};

periodize[data_] := 
 Append[data, {N@L, 
   data[[1, 
    2]]}];(*for periodic interpolation*)tmax = 2; nGrid = 31(*91*);
inicos[x_] = c Cos[(\[Pi]*x)/L];

Block[{int}, int[u_, x_?NumericQ, t_ /; t == 0] := (cnt++;
   NIntegrate[
    inicos'''[xp]*Cot[\[Pi] (x - xp)/(2*L)], {xp, x - L, x, x + L}, 
    Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", 
      Method -> "PrincipalValue"}, PrecisionGoal -> 8, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 10]);
 int[uppp_?VectorQ, xv_?VectorQ, t_?NumericQ] := Function[x, cnt++;
    NIntegrate[
     Interpolation[periodize@Transpose@{xv, uppp}, xp, 
       PeriodicInterpolation -> True]*Cot[\[Pi] (x - xp)/(2*L)], {xp, 
      x - L, x, x + L}, 
     Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", 
       Method -> "PrincipalValue"}, PrecisionGoal -> 8, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 10]] /@ xv;
 (*monitor while integrating pde*)Clear[foo];
 cnt = 0;
 PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{foo, cnt, Clock[Infinity]};
 (*broken down NDSolve call*)
 Internal`InheritedBlock[{MapThread}, {state} = 
   NDSolve`ProcessEquations[sys, u, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "MinPoints" -> nGrid, "MaxPoints" -> nGrid, 
        "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}(*,Method\[Rule]{"StiffnessSwitching",
      "NonstiffTest"\[Rule]Automatic}*)}, 
    AccuracyGoal -> Infinity,(*WorkingPrecision\[Rule]20,*)
    MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], StepMonitor :> (foo = t)];
  Unprotect[MapThread];
  MapThread[f_, data_, 1] /; ! FreeQ[f, int] := f @@ data;
  Protect[MapThread];
  NDSolve`Iterate[state, {0, tmax}];
  sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state]]]

Plot3D[Evaluate[Re[u[x, t] /. sol]], {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, 2}, 
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic]
Plot3D[Evaluate[Re[u[x, t] /. sol]], {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, 2}, 
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {-10^6, 10^6}]
Plot3D[Evaluate[Log[Abs[u[x, t] /. sol]]], {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, 2}, 
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 3]
Now the main result of this study: the last problem has an exact solution $u(x,t)=c e^{-kt}\cos{(\pi x/L)}$ with $k=(a/2L)(\pi/L)^3$.Thus, the integral term contributes to the attenuation of the initial data. The numerical solution shows the growth of the solution, which should not be.

Comment: Is the aim of normalizing the domain size to 1 to deploy as many as possible points to resolve the solution and prevent warning like "estimated initial error on the specified spatial grid exceeds prescribed error tolerance"?

Comment: @user55777 The convergence of the method improves on the interval `(x,-1/2,1/2)`.

Comment: by setting `dx = (L - del)/6 - del` and `ParallelTable[{{x, t}, ...}, {x, -L+del, L-del, dx}, {t, 0, tmax, .2*tmax}]`, you actually divided a half domain `L` into 6 subdomains. I have difficulty in understanding why substracting a small segment `del` from each subdomain and why it is 6 subdomain?

Comment: @user55777 we use `del` to eliminate singularity and 6 to speed up calculations (there are 12 subdomain).

Comment: $L-del-(-L+del)=2L-2del$ but $12dx=12[(L-del)/6-del]=2L-14del$, they are not equal. How `dx` can be the x step in `ParallelTable`? What is the motivation to choose `del=10^-6`?

Comment: can I use `U[i][x*1/2/7, t/L0]` to recover the unscaled solution, is it right? Thank you!

Comment: There is not much difference if we take `dx=L/6`. Use `U[i][x/14,t/14]` with `{x,-7,7}, {t,0,28}`.